# Spring boot Eureka: Use shared instance without registration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

We are developing a system (based on Netflix microservice stack) that uses quite a few microservices. In some cases, in order to test something locally, it is required to start several microservices in order to be able to perform happy-path testing. 
I find this quite annoying, since services ran locally consume quite a bit resources and since I don't change them in particular use case, I'd expect I can use stable set of them from remote peer.

I'd like to ask if it is feasible to prepare environment like this:

1. Localhost:

a) Tested microservice

b) Local eureka for registering a) and c)

c) Local zuul for gateway

2. Shared machine

a) Shared eureka

b..z) Bunch of stateless microservices that can be reused by dev team for their tests.

In such scenario I'd expect that shared eureka would not register services from my local machine, but only serve as a shared pool of (stable) services for reuse.

Can you provide example of such configuration or propose different approach for such development environment?

[EDIT]
I've tried setting up following config to my local eureka:

```
client:
  fetch-registry: true
  register-with-eureka: false
  serviceUrl:
    defaultZone: http://<My shared eureka>:8762/eureka/
```

But I got my local services registered on shared anyway...

Comment: "and since I don't change them in particular use case, I'd expect I can use stable set of them from remote peer." This looks like a unit test for me. Why not just mock the responses of the services?

Comment: @YannicKlem I rather try to find out a generic solution to develop new functionalities with possibility to connect this functionality to stable development ecosystem before committing (I believe it is called "platform leasing" pattern)

Comment: Ok. So based on what you showed us. The indent is wrong. currently eureka.client.register-with-eureka is not set. But i guess thats just a mistake in the post and not in your application.yml?

Comment: corrected the indentation in inital question. I believe register-with-eureka as false is what I actually want to achieve: have localhost:eureka fetch shared:Eureka registry, but do not register itself.

Comment: looks good to me. Can you provide a minimal working sample that shows this effect? A little github repo would be nice. I'll have a look at it when im at home.